# Is there a way to make a MeshPhongMaterial ignore all lights

Tags: three.js

I am using ThreeJS r67
I have a static room with lighting baked so lights do not need to affect it, but I also have a person in the room that does need the lighting. Is there a way to set all the materials in the room to ignore the lights?

Comment: MeshBasicMaterial ignores the lights

Comment: The only issue is that I am loading from collada, and there is no way for me to go from MeshPhong to Mesh Basic

Comment: According to the ColladaLoader.js (in three.js r67) lines 3550-3572 you can specify in the collada model file what type of material to create. You are probably using `blinn` or `phong` and you need to change that to `constant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ColladaLoader.js (in three.js r67) lines 3550-3572 you can specify in the collada model file what type of material to create. You are probably using `blinn` or `phong` and you need to change that to `constant`.

Comment: I would upvote this, but I need one more reputation point to do it. This fix helped a lot.